# What is meant by Hibernate as JPA provider?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

The Java Persistence API is a Java specification for managing, persisting and accessing data between objects and relation database. Hibernate is an ORM tool

How does the Hibernate work as the JPA provider?

Comment: Heck, internet search is down again ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you know how interfaces and classes work in Java?

Simply put: JPA provides the interfaces, and Hibernate the concrete classes that implement these interfaces.

There are other implementations as well, such as EclipseLink or OpenJPA.

So when people say you are using Hibernate as JPA provider, that means that you're using Hibernate classes wherever you use a JPA interface.